# Partial Italic and Bold text in R

Tags: r

I want to label a subgroup in R-plot as **Non-*Enterobacteriaceae***

```
text(-1.5, c(21), pos = 4, c("Non-Enterobacteriaceae"), font = 2, cex = 0.8)
```

Changing the font = 4 changes the complete word Non-Enterobacteriaceae to ***Non-Enterobacteriaceae***
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of the `?plotmath` formatting options. For example

```
plot(c(1,10), c(1,10))
text(5, 5, pos = 4, quote(bold("Non-") * bolditalic("Enterobacteriaceae")), cex = 3)
```

[image]